# Coding a bisection algorithm using matlab (numerical analysis)

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

To code the bisection algorithm. We assume that f at the two end-points a and b are of
different signs. We will return the approximated solution when $b_{n}$ − $a_{n}$ < 2ε
or when we have found the exact root.

```
% bisection.m

function root=bisection(a,b,epsilon)
  fa=fun(a);  
  err = (b-a)/2;
  p=a+err;
  fp=fun(p);

  while and((fp∼=0),(err>=epsilon))
    if fa*fp < 0
      b=p;
    else
      a=p;
      fa=fp;
    end;
    err=err/2;
    p=a+err;
    fp=fun(p);
  end;

  root=p;
```

Modify the code so that we will stop when |f(p)| < ε instead

What i tried

I think that it is form this part of the code onwards that need to be modified

while and((fp∼=0),(err>=epsilon))

So instead of having err>=eplison we make the error less than elipson. Now i know the code makes use of thw while loop and im finding ways on how to stop the while loop in order to stop the code. Could anyone help me in this. Thanks

Comment: You want the while loop to execute while the absolute value of fp is greater than or equal to  epsilon, so use `while (abs(fp)>=epsilon)`

Comment: Oh but where is the point at which the loop would stop? Because in that case the loop will keep executing, so there need to be a stopping condition?

Comment: It's generaly a good idea to have a maximum number of iterations. So something like while(abs(fp) >= epsilon OR num_iter != 500) do: bla bla num_iter = num_iter +1

Comment: You could also use an for loop and having a  if(abs(fp)<epsilon): break line in it.

Comment: There is a fundamental problem in your implementation which you need to guard against. Specifically, the operation fa*fp can underflow to zero, leading you to take the wrong branch. You avoid this pitfall by comparing the sign of fa with the sign of fb. MATLAB has a sign function which you can use. Moreover, you will want to have two tolerances, epsilon and delta. You should use one for the residual, i.e abs(fp), and one for you current error bound, i.e. abs(err).